# (JSFUnit) visit many url's in same session

Tags: java, jsf, jsfunit

I am beginner in JSFUnit and related technologies. I was wondering: is it possible to change the url without creating a new JSFSession object? I.e. I would like to simulate the situation where the user types in a new address in his/her address bar.

**Additional Information**

The problem is that I have many links in my facelets page, that cannot be assigned ids because they are created inside a ui:repeat element.

**Workaround**

Use a cookie to restore the session between different JSFSessions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course.

You could have a button in your xhtml/jsp page. This button will lead to the requested page.

For example, if you have login page, and the user would like to go to test page so in your JSFUnit write:

```
jsfSession = new JSFSession("start.jsf");
client = jsfSession.getJSFClientSession();
client.click("Login");
```

and in `start.jsf` page have:

```
<h:form>
    <h:commandButton id = "Login" value="Login" action="#{loginBean.doLogin}"/>
</h:form>
```

where in your `loginBean`

```
public void doLogin(){
   return "test.jsf";
}
```

In this way you can simulate the same session for the user.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I added additional information, as to why your solution is not applicable to my problem.